# Add specific phrase after every product title including the discounted price?

Tags: php, jquery, javascript, woocommerce-offtopic

Our current price set up has a *regular price*, a *sale price*, and *promo code price*.

So if the *regular price is $34.99* then our *sale price* would be *$24.99*

All our *promo code prices are 20% off the sale price*. Meaning our *promo code price* would be *$19.99*.

---

In all our product's titles `<h1>` we feature the *promo code price*. For example: If our products name was

## Microwave Oven g3400

and the sale price set in woocommerce was 24.99. Than we would than calculate 20% off that and display it in the title like so:

## Microwave Oven g3400 - $19.99 with promo code: STEALS

---

So instead of doing this manually on every product since we have thousands of products. Could we just insert this straight into the products title and calculate the difference (20% off) from the products sale price and display it as part of the title with the promo code text?

I'm thinking this could be accomplished in both jquery or PHP and am open to any solution.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not really familiar with woocommerce, but I imagine you can just use the appropriate variable/function in the correct place inside the theme's templates.

Comment: Yes I am sure u can which is why I am asking how to do it :)

Thank you for looking at my thread!

Comment: @PortalP - People vote down for different reasons, so please do not take it personally. It maybe someone who thought your question should not be asked due to its simplicity, or maybe it is someone who thought this question does not have the supporting code for it (i.e., show what you attempted). This is a community site, and voting up/down will help ensure the best questions and answers are written here. Cheers.

Comment: @PortalP while many things in WC may be a post not everything is - WC installs more than 13 database tables to manage data separately from WP. It also does a lot of other things on it's own - including it's own template tags and own actions. While in WP alone you'd accomplish this with a [`the_title`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) hook, it's impossible to say if this will work for WC without having an extremely intimate knowledge of WC itself. So, unfortunately, this question is off-topic here - it can't be definitively answered with just WP expertise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not giving much detail, but I will do as much as I can.

The best way to approach this, is to do that directly via PHP (without jQuery). So, assuming that the product title is displayed via `the_title()` between `<h1>` tags, as such:

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

Then I would add the following *pseudo-code* as follows:

```
<h1><?php the_title(); ?>
    <span>
    <?php
        if (promo-price exists) {
            // 1. Code to get promo price and promo code from DB
            $promo_price = Somehow get from DB;
            $promo_code = Also get from DB;

            // 2. Code to display text
            $price_details = sprintf(' - $%d with promo code: %s', $promo_price, $promo_code);
            echo $price_details;
        }
    ?>
    </span>
</h1>
```

Remember, this is *pseudo-code* and you must modify according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am not sure though because that way would involve editing WooCommerce core files. Which like WordPress. You arent suppose to do.

Comment: You are not changing core files. This is a them file/page, right?

Comment: oh i could create a page template tho..

Comment: Exactly. Again, you know your environment better than mine. But if you would like to customize an existing them, it is better to create a child theme with the customization there.